# How to pre bundle maps with skobbler maps 3.0?

Tags: ios, sdk, maps, offline, skmaps

I'm not able to make skobbler maps works with a prebundled map with SDK 3.0.

I uploaded a sample project [here](https://github.com/augmentedworks/SKMaps_iOS_3) with a London map in the SKMaps.bundle. It cannot render the maps. (please use the SKMapsSwiftDemo on the repo)

I followed the tutorial for the 2.5 on the skobbler's blog. Did anything change?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've create a 3.0.1 (latest version) Swift build (demo project) that has the London map prebundled.
It can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pd85i4304hxdvmd/SKMapsDemoSwift_3_0_1_prebundledLondon.zip?dl=0).

The demo project is configured to start in offline to indicate that only London is visible.

Comment: Thank you, it works. My problem were the meta files. I used the ones from the demo project shipped with sdk version 3.0.0. They didn't work. The one I downloaded from your version 3.0.1 work. The problem is that version 3.0.1 seems it's not released officially yet: http://developer.skobbler.com/release-notes